# amp app banner does not show in android and IOS device working fine

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, amp-html

I am using following code below which is not showing AMP app banner.

[Here is the example.](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-app-banner&format=websites&_gl=1*1tf5qvf*_ga*YW1wLTQwNW9GM3l3NXZwWkVtSC1kVFo3bEE.&mode=Galaxy+S5)

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-app-banner" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-app-banner-0.1.js"></script>
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=828256236, app-argument=medium://p/9ea61abf530f">
<link rel="manifest" href="/amp-app-banner-manifest.json">
```

```
{
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "com.medium.reader",
      "url": "android-app://com.medium.reader/https/medium.com/p/cb7f223fad86"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello. I'm running into a similar issue right now. Have you managed to get it to work?

Comment: "The Android manifest href attribute must be served over https." according to the amp app banner documentation (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-app-banner/) - try to use an absolute manifest link

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to get a bit more info. but based on what is shown, I could see that there is no layout attribute  that is passed and this can be an issue sometimes. Give this a try

https://www.nxtut.com/amp-app-banner-example/

Comment: I have already mentioned an example: https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-app-banner&format=websites&_gl=1*1tf5qvf*_ga*YW1wLTQwNW9GM3l3NXZwWkVtSC1kVFo3bEE.&mode=Galaxy+S5

Comment: Link is down, any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

**follow below instruction to see the output.**

1) open chrome enter your amp page URL

2) open the console and click on 3 dots.

3) inside more tools select network condition

4) inside network condition uncheck user agent automatically checkbox and manually select firefox iPad and reload the page.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how this helps fixing the problem?